# How to encrypt content to file from batch prompt in GnuPG?

Tags: windows, gnupg

I am using the below command to encrypt a string to a file, but it always fails with the error message "gpg --encrypt needs input".

```
gpg.exe --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --armor --sign --recipient test@email.com --homedir "c:\gnupg" --encrypt 1 > "test.gpg"
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

GnuPG always expects input from a file or from STDIN. To pass a string into STDIN, use `ECHO` on Windows systems or `echo` on unix systems and pipe into `gpg`:

```
ECHO 1 | gpg [other options] --encrypt
echo 1 | gpg [other options] --encrypt
```

Since you already expect the passphrase from file descriptor 0 (which is STDIN), you'll have to either

- provide any of passphrase and data to be signed from another location
- pipe in both strings separated by a newline character, which is easy with `sh`/`bash` on unix systems (`echo -e "passphrase\ndata" | gpg --sign --encrypt`), but [requires a rather hacky-ish solution on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132799/695343) (I'm not too familiar with the Windows command prompt, but likely you'll have to choose one of the solutions with single `ECHO` command).